# Equivalent defintions of minimal sufficient statistics

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, sufficient-statistics

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic#Minimal_sufficiency) claims that the statistic $S(X)$ is minimal sufficient if and only if

$f_{\theta}(x)/f_{\theta}(y) $ is independent of $\theta$ $\iff$ $S(x) = S(y)$.

It is also claimed that this is a direct consequence of Fisher's factorization theorem. However, I do not see how this is a direct consequence.

As a definition of sufficient statistic, I know that the following two are equivalent:

- $S(x) = S(y)$ $\implies$  $f_{\theta}(x)/f_{\theta}(y) $ is independent of $\theta$
- The conditional distribution of $X$ given $S(X)$ does not depend on $\theta$.

As a definition of minimal sufficient, I use that a sufficient statistic $S(X)$ is a minimal sufficient statistic if and only if for all sufficient statistics $S'$, $S'(x) = S'(y)$ implies $S(x)=S(y)$.

I can prove that if $f_{\theta}(x)/f_{\theta}(y) $ is independent of $\theta$ $\iff$ $S(x) = S(y)$, then $S(X)$ is minimal sufficient

The direction $S(x) = S(y)$ $\implies$  $f_{\theta}(x)/f_{\theta}(y) $ is independent of $\theta$  is implies the fact $S$ is sufficient. Now if $S'$ is sufficient, then  $S'(x) = S'(y)$ implies $f_{\theta}(x)/f_{\theta}(y) $ is independent of $\theta$, which implies $S(x) = S(y)$. So  $S(X)$ is minimal sufficient.

But I am struggeling with showing that if $S(X)$ is minimal sufficient, then  $f_{\theta}(x)/f_{\theta}(y) $ is independent of $\theta$ $\iff$ $S(x) = S(y)$. I don't see how the factorization theorem helps here.